# multivariable limit of $\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that limit of $f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0) } \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}$ does not exist but show as well the following holds: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left( \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} f(x,y)\right)=0=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}\left( \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x,y)\right)$. How to do that? I guess that squeeze theorem should be applied but i have problems with its application.

Comment: Can't you solve the iterated limits?

Comment: Hint: Consider what happens as $(x,y) \to 0$ along the line $y=x$.

Comment: Main problem i have is with iterated limits for the "main" limit i am trying to substitute $y=x$ and $y=-x$ and i think this shows more or less that limit does not exist because then i have two limits of different value

Comment: I can't understand "Main problem i have is with iterated limits for the "main" limit i am trying". What does 'iterated limits for the main limit' mean?

Comment: main problem i have is with iterated limits of the function, with multi variable (not iterated) limit i think i know more or less the solution

Comment: @Krowskir What is $\lim_\limits{y\to 0}\left(\frac{y^2}{y^2+(1-y)^2}\right)$? What is $\lim \limits_{y\to 0}\left(\frac{4y^2}{4y^2+(4-y)^2}\right)$? Given any real $x$, what is it $\lim \limits_{y\to 0}\left(\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}\right)$?

Comment: more or less i got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=x$:
$$f(x,x)=\frac{x^4}{x^4+(x-x)^2}=1$$
This limit is different from $0$. Therefore this limit doesn't exist.